# How to use Swal in Angular project?

Tags: angular, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Well, I have an angular project and want to use swal2 on it, but i don't know how to integrate it.

Help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install it with the command,

```
npm install --save sweetalert
```

and then in the component,

```
import swal from 'sweetalert';
```

use it as,

```
 swal({
      content: component.location.nativeElement
    }).then(() => {
      component.destroy();
    });
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sweetalert-aeumjz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**